# Reason: image not found tensorflow GPU

Tags: tensorflow, nvidia, cublas

I have installed tensorflow GPU with Nvidia CUDA on mac book pro 2012mid (Nvidia GT 650M)

But when I run the simple tensorflow program, `image not found` error occurs.

I have googled around and found this error is related with cuda installation.

[[[What I have checked are]]]

libcudart.8,0.dylib is here

```
/usr/local/cuda/lib/libcudart.8.0.dylib
```

and environment setting looks propery.

```
(tensorflow) koala:tensorWorkspace daichi$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/cuda/lib:
(tensorflow) koala:tensorWorkspace daichi$ echo $CUDA_HOME
/usr/local/cuda
```

Is therre any place I should check???

error log is below.

```
(tensorflow) koala:tensorWorkspace whitebear$ python3 hello.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/whitebear/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/Users/whitebear/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/whitebear/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Users/whitebear/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Users/whitebear/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/whitebear/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcublas.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/whitebear/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
  Reason: image not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/Users/whitebear/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Users/whitebear/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Users/whitebear/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/whitebear/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/Users/whitebear/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/whitebear/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Users/whitebear/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Users/whitebear/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/whitebear/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcublas.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/whitebear/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
  Reason: image not found


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: The library causing the problem is CUBLAS. Have you checked that it is installed and in a path where tensorflow can find it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. CUBLAS is cuda toolkit??? I have installed cuda toolkit and my nvcc --version shows the message like this `nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:46_CST_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61`

Comment: and path LD_LIBRARY_PATH, CUDA_HOME is correctly set.

Comment: I solved it is because of SIP https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5141 I stoped SIP by this article and works correctly http://www.macworld.com/article/2986118/security/how-to-modify-system-integrity-protection-in-el-capitan.html

Comment: Then please add your solution as an answer. It is ok to answer your own questions  on [SO]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is SIP installed from MAC os 10.11

Stop SIP according to  this [article](http://www.macworld.com/article/2986118/security/how-to-modify-system-integrity-protection-in-el-capitan.html)

The problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else seeing this error, the same traceback can occur if CUDA toolkit is not properly installed (and CUBLAS is not available).  Reinstalling CUDA toolkit fixed this for me.